# SQL - Update value based on previous record and condition

Tags: sql

I have a requirement to update a table based on previous record if the Code value is B.

Here the UpdatedAmount has to be replaced with previous value of RunningTotal only if the Code is B. It has to be updated with the value in UpdatedAmount itself.

I tried to use Lead but it just take the previous value but not the Updated one.
I'm new to sql and just wanted to check if there is any options to achieve this.

Using Lead I got below output

| Id | SNO | Rank | Amount | RunningTotal | Code | UpdatedAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC01 | 4 | 0 | 0 | A | 0 |
| 1 | ABC02 | 3 | 0 | 0 | B | 4 |
| 1 | ABC03 | 2 | 4 | 4 | B | 8 |
| 1 | ABC04 | 1 | 4 | 8 | B | Null |

This is the desired output

| Id | SNO | Rank | Amount | RunningTotal | Code | UpdatedAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC01 | 4 | 0 | 0 | A | 0 |
| 1 | ABC02 | 3 | 0 | 0 | B | 8 |
| 1 | ABC03 | 2 | 4 | 4 | B | 8 |
| 1 | ABC04 | 1 | 4 | 8 | A | 8 |

Comment: Please tag the SQL dialect that you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused about the words "previous" and "updated" in the question but I suspect a solution is going to look something like this.

```
with dataX as (
    select *,
        sum(Amount) over (partition by Id order by SNO) as RunningTotal,
        count(case when Code <> 'B' then 1 end) over (partition by Id order by SNO desc) as grp
    from T
)
select *,
    max(RunningTotal) over (partition by Id, grp) as UpdatedAmount
from dataX;
```

The query presumes that each id will get a separate calculation and that ordering is done by the `SNO` column. Some of my uncertainty would be addressed simply by posting the code from an unsuccessful attempt.

Comment: Thanks a lot... This solved my issue... Accepting this as answer